# Python IDE built into Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, ide

Hi I develop in Visual Studio 2008 a lot and would like to find an addin like vsphp which  enables intellisense and debugging in Visual Studio. Is IronStudio what I am looking for? As far as I understand IronStudio is a Plugin for .NET.

If there is no Plugin for Visual Studio 2008 whats a great IDE for a python newbee who loves Visual Studio (hate netbeans and eclipse sorry just don't feel the love)

Also if IronPython Studio is an IDE do I want the Isolated or Integrated Version? I don't seem to understand the name.

I installed integrated and got this: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-02-11_1750.png :( no console like here: http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio

Comment: You want integrated *I think*

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/), I haven't tried it extensively but heard good things about it.

It's not an addon to Visual Studio, it's an independent IDE.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar dilemma when I first started writing in Python. I couldn't find any plugins for VS so I tried a few alternatives:

- IDLE - comes packaged with Python and works but felt very cludgy to me
- [Wingware Python IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) - not free, but seemed to have pretty good debugging capabilities
- [e-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) - has nice syntax highlighting but running Python script from it frequently causes issues.
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) - is what I now use - syntax highlighting, auto-completion, debugging capabilities etc. etc.

There's a couple of reviews of options that might be of use to you:

- [Jonathan Ellis's Programming Blog](http://spyced.blogspot.com/2005/09/review-of-6-python-ides.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments)

Personally, I'd recommend Eclipse + PyDev :-)

**[Edit]** Iron Python looks pretty cool - might have to check that one out!

**[Update 25/04/2013]** I just use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) these days. Absolutely fantastic IDE and it even understands DJango

Comment: pydev seems to have support for ironpython console, intellisense(including some .net intellisense, unsure about ironpython debugging though).

Comment: Python Tools for VS seems to be the answer to your question but if you try Wing IDE be sure to use the Edit > Keyboard Personality menu to change to Visual Studio emulation.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that you have Visual Studio 2008 and the VS 2k8 Shell Integrated Redistributable package, IronPython Studio Integrated will plug into the VS 2k8 IDE.

[Visual Studio 2008 Shell (Integrated)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=40646580-97FA-4698-B65F-620D4B4B1ED7&displaylang=en)

[Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 Shell (Integrated)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6a64e02-6fd6-41e3-a3fd-399d174a84b7&displaylang=en)

Comment: A little more detail or a link to more detail would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Java based IDE's are no good they tend to be fat, slow, and unpolished.
Eclipse has a poor programming paradigm that is unnecesarrily confusing.  The many IDE vendors made a mistake by quitting their native products and basing them instead on Eclipse.  They can't differentiate themselves and the experience is awful.  Real shame actually.  VS needs competition but they all rolled over and died.

Comment: Eclipse is an amazing ide, especially for java and that is why so many ides are based of it. Its also much easier to extend then VS. I'm not saying some companies might not make nice standalone ides but most who make eclipse plugins and/or eclipse based ides would have made substantially worse standalone ides.

Answer (score 4):

[IronPython tools for Visual Studio 2010.](http://www.ironpython.net) is fairly well intergrated.  I know you asked for 2008 but now that 2010 is out ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'll second one of Jon's suggestions: PyDev and Eclipse.  This is great if you are already using Eclipse for other development.

You can grab it (and links to the Eclipse platform) from here:
  http://pydev.sourceforge.net/download.html

Answer (score 2):

Python tools for Visual Studio 2010 is out now http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/41236

Comment: I think this is a better link: http://pytools.codeplex.com/. And no, Visual Studio Express is not supported.

Comment: According to the documentation (see http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20-%20details), you can use the free Visual Studio 2010 Shell rather than Visual Studio Express.

Answer (score 1):

IronPython and Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)  are different things.

PTVS http://pytools.codeplex.com/ is a free & open source plug-in for Visual Studio 2010 from Microsoft's Developer Division. It allows you to code python using Visual Studio, gaining the benefits to use all the major productivity features of Visual Studio.

PTVS is compatible with IronPython and CPython, which are Python distributions where you run your code.

CPython is the traditional Python distribution while IronPython http://ironpython.net  is an alternate that allows you to run python over .Net and allows you to user other .Net libraries on your applications.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the Aptana studio. It is similar to the Eclipse and PyDev. But is an separate IDE based upon python and web development.

Answer (score 0):

Three different things 
- Python Tools for Visual Studio 
- IronPython
- IronPython Studio

Only this last (I think) allows for visual Gui design.
but it is dead

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: IronPyhton Studio, developed by Clarius consulting labs, is a full IDEbased on VS 2008 Shell runtime. [link] (https://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/) . With it one builds gui application using only drag and drop for forms, buttons and in general controls like in VB.net or C#.net. But the project seems dead. I cannot find any integrated (no xml files and two programs) visual gui designer for python.