# How to get Python syntax highlighting for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

Visual Studio 2008 is great as text editor, but it lacks Python syntax highlighting, can I get this as an add-on? Where can I find it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537689/python-ide-built-into-visual-studio-2008

Comment: @Adrian not exactly a duplicate, but its answers were helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered installing IronPython and using that to edit your work?

- http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio